# BATCH "system cannot find file" when folder name contains dots

Tags: batch-file, directory

In this part of my script I use robocopy to copy the content of a folder into another one but if the source folder has 1 or more dots in the name it fails: "The system cannot find the file specified."

I tried with move and xcopy too but same thing. Any fix?

here is the full script:

```
set currentfolder=UserData\
set Index=1
for /d %%D in (%currentfolder%*) do (
set "folderlist[!Index!]=%%~nD"
set /a Index+=1
)

set /a UBound=Index-1

for /l %%i in (1,1,%UBound%) do (
for %%f in ("!folderlist!") do (
echo;  %%i. !folderlist[%%i]!
))

    set /p FolderChoice= Now please select a folder : 

    robocopy "UserData\!folderlist[%FolderChoice%]!" "UserData\newfoldername" /IS /IT
```

Comment: Note: For __FOR__ the extension is everything from last dot to end of name independent on string assigned to the loop variable is a folder or a file name. Folder names can contain also one or more dots although this is unusual. For that reason use for folder names `%%~nxD` and not just `%%~nD` to reference the complete folder name without its path.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "folderlist[!Index!]=%%~nD"
```

should be

```
set "folderlist[!Index!]=%%~nxD"
```

To select both the `N`ame and e`X`tension